# AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a GUI with tkinter. I am designing a login system and it chooses between admin or safetyteam. The problem is in the "choice" method I designed. It is to show the next frame based on the choice between the previous choice but fails.

The error is:

> AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'choice'

**Note: This is not the full code yet.**

## Myscript:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font  as tkfont 
import webbrowser

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

    # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
    # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
    # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Main, TeamLogin, AdminLogin, Admin, SafetyTeam):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

        # put all of the pages in the same location;
        # the one on the top of the stacking order
        # will be the one that is visible.
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("Main")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, classname):
        '''Returns an instance of a page given it's class name as a string'''
        for page in self.frames.values():
            if str(page.__class__.__name__) == classname:
                return page
        return None


    def loginS(self):
      u1 = userS.get()
      p1 = passS.get()
      username_entry1.delete(0, END)
      password_entry1.delete(0, END)
      list_of_files = os.listdir()
      if u1 in list_of_files:
          file1 = open(safetyteamfile, "r")
          verify = file1.read().splitlines()
          if p1 in verify:
            controller.show_frame("Safetyteam")
          else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "invalid username or password")

    def loginA(self):
      u2 = userA.get()
      p2 = passA.get()
      username_entry2.delete(0, END)
      password_entry2.delete(0, END)
      list_of_files = os.listdir()
      if u2 in list_of_files:
        file2 = open(adminfile, "r")
        verify1 = file2.read().splitlines()
        if p2 in verify1:
            pass
            controller.show_frame("Admin")
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "invalid username or password")
```

## Main code:

```
class Main(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        global CheckVar1
        CheckVar1 = IntVar()
        L1 = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to Smart Safety System", font=controller.title_font).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        L2 = tk.Label(self, text="Log in as:", font=controller.title_font).pack()
        b1 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Safety Team", variable = CheckVar1, value=1)
        b2 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Admin", variable = CheckVar1, value=2) 
        b3 = tk.Button(self, text= "submit",command=lambda: controller.choice)
        b1.pack()
        b2.pack()
        b3.pack()

    def choice():
        if(CheckVar1.get()==1):
            self.show_frame("TeamLogin")

        if(CheckVar1.get()==2):
            self.show_frame("AdminLogin")
```

## Team login code:

```
class TeamLogin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        L1 = tk.Label(self, text="Safety Team Login", font=controller.title_font).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)


        L2 = tk.Label(self,text="Enter username and password", font=controller.title_font).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=20)
        global userS
        userS = StringVar()
        global passS
        passS = StringVar()


        L3 = tk.Label(self,text="username", font=controller.title_font).pack()
        e1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=userS).pack()
        L4 = Label(self,text="password", font=controller.title_font).pack()
        e2 = tk.Entry(self,textvariable=passS).pack()
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Login", command=lambda: controller.loginS).pack()
```

## Safety team code:

```
class SafetyTeam(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
```

## Admin login code:

```
class AdminLogin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        L1 = tk.Label(self, text="Admin Login", font=controller.title_font).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        L2 = tk.Label(self,text="Enter username and password", font=controller.title_font).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=20)

        global userA
        userA = StringVar()
        global passA
        passA = StringVar()


        L3 = tk.Label(self,text="username", font=controller.title_font).pack()
        e1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=userA).pack()
        L4 = tk.Label(self,text="password", font=controller.title_font).pack()
        e2 = tk.Entry(self,textvariable=passA).pack()
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Login", command=lambda: controller.loginA).pack()
```

## Main Admin code:

```
class Admin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tip: combine a few py. files into one. For example gui.py has everything related to GUI. Login has one py.file (if needed admin.py and team.py but preferably both have their own classes in the single pyfile) but not six separate files. This will give you headaches in maintenance and you will loose oversight. Finally, you have main.py that joins and runs your main script.

Comment: Once I've joined everything in one single py.file I saw indentation issue in the admin class and GUI which shows only a header. Is that with you also the case? Not able to reproduce attribute error.

Comment: why are you using python classes and not using the _self_ keyword? _global_ is so inefficient when you would like to implement this modular approach! use the self keyword inside the **Main code** for _choice_.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question. There are other useful informations. For example it show line with code which makes problem and name of script with this code.

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please reduce this down to a [mcve].

Comment: What do you think `controller.choice` is supposed to do? Like the error is telling you, the controller doesn't have a `choice` method.